# php min and max variables not working in mysql statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using jQuery slider.  I am using the following code to post the variables to my php form.

The variables are posted, and I use

`$mincost = $_get['mincost']; and $maxcost = $_get['maxcost'];`

to get these variables.

When I run this through mysql, I see a mysql error, I tried:

```
`price` BETWEEN '$mincost' AND '$maxcost'
```

this shows no results and no errors

Also tried:

```
`price` BETWEEN ".$mincost." AND ".$maxcost."
```

and:

```
`price` BETWEEN $mincost AND $maxcost
```

these both show:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064
```

The variables are being posted because I echoed them on a test page.

If I set the min and max variables manually, this works.

Comment: Add complete mysql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **`$_GET`** to retrieve the URL parameters, instead of `$_get`. Also, cast the strings to `integer`

```
$mincost = (int) $_GET['mincost'];
$maxcost = (int) $_GET['maxcost'];
```

**EDIT**

*The variables are posted*

If data is `post`ed, you should use `$_POST`.

```
$mincost = (int) $_POST['mincost'];
$maxcost = (int) $_POST['maxcost'];
```

If you're not sure it the data is *POSTed* or sent in the querystring in URL, use **`$_REQUEST`**

```
$mincost = (int) $_REQUEST['mincost'];
$maxcost = (int) $_REQUEST['maxcost'];
```

Comment: using GET for the form, ive tried both GET and REQUEST, the query doesnt show any errors or any results, using ".$mincost." , '$mincost', $mincost, and tried with pdo :mincost - still no results and I know the query works because I have tried setting variables manually and also echoed them